# AMQP/RabbitMQ - Only real-time messages/passthrough queue

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am building a website which receives real-time updates about soccer matches. I am using RabbitMQ to send the updates to the clients (JS website and Android/iOS apps).

**The clients should only receive real-time updates.** In other words, a client should only receive updates when the user is logged in. No history is kept.

To achieve this behavior, I was thinking about the following architecture:

- A fanout exchange in RabbitMQ.
- Each user has a dedicated queue, which is bound to the exchange. This queue is created when the user account is created.
- For these queues, the queue property `x-message-ttl` with value of 0 is set. See below.
- When the user logs in, the client consumes the queue of the corresponding user.
- Messages are sent to the exchange by the backend, and forwarded to all queues. When a user is not logged in, the message will be discarded immediately, as `x-message-ttl` is set to 0.

Is this a correct usage of AMQP/RabbitMQ to achieve real-time notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no - some of your premises are wrong.

- `In other words, a client should only receive updates when the user is logged in.` When the user is not logged in, simply drop the connection to RMQ and that's it.
- `Each user has a dedicated queue, which is bound to the exchange. This queue is created when the user account is created.` The queue should be created only after the connection to RMQ is established, in that way you are also covering the `When a user is not logged in, the message will be discarded immediately` part.
- No need to set TTL to 0.
- `Messages are sent to the exchange by the backend, and forwarded to all queues` Just to be clear, it's the RabbitMQ that does "forwarding" from exchange to queues.

Comment: If the queue is created after logging in, does this mean that the queue should be declared as `auto-delable`?

Comment: By logging in do you mean logging in to your website, or logging in - establishing connection to RMQ? If you don't want the user to the messages that he missed while logged out (from the website/webapp) than make it auto-delete.

Comment: Thank you, got it now. I did not understand that queues are meant to be created/deleted on the fly. I thought that queues should be more or less static. I will try it out.

Comment: YOu are welcome. Well they could be, but it's up to the use case.